# Can ProcessPoolExecutor work with yield generator in Python?

Tags: python, linux, generator, large-files, concurrent.futures

I have a python script aiming to process some a large file and write the results in a new txt file. I simplified it as Code example 1.
Code example 1:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import os

def process(args):
    parm1, parm2, parm3, output_file = args
    scores = []
    # do something with scores...
    if parm1:
        scores = [parm2, sum(parm3)]
    else:
        scores = [parm2/len(parm3), sum(parm3)/len(parm3)]
    # create result
    result = '\t'.join(scores) + '\n'
    output_file.write(result)

def main(large_file_path, output_path, max_processes):
    #do something ...
    with open(large_file_path, 'r') as large_file, open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
        arg_list = []
        parm1, parm2, parm3 = False, 0, []
        for line in large_file:
            if line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            else:
                # do something to update parm1, parm2, parm3...
                data = line.strip().split('\t')
                parm1 = data[0] > 0
                parm2 = data[1]
                parm3 = data[2:]
                # add to list
                arg_list.append((parm1, parm2, parm3, output_file))
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_processes) as executor:
            executor.map(process, arg_list, chunksize=int(max_processes/2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    large_path = "/path/to/large_file"
    output_path = f"para_scores.txt"
    max_processes = int(os.cpu_count()/2)# Set the maximum number of processes

    main(large_path, output_path, max_processes)
```

I realized that `arg_list` might be quite large if the `large_file` is very large. I am not sure if there is enough free memory for it. Then I tried to use yield generator instead of just a python list as Code example 2, which runs normally but does not generate anything.
Code example 2:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import os

def process(args):
    parm1, parm2, parm3, output_file = args
    scores = []
    # do something with scores...
    if parm1:
        scores = [parm2, sum(parm3)]
    else:
        scores = [parm2/len(parm3), sum(parm3)/len(parm3)]
    # create result
    result = '\t'.join(scores) + '\n'
    output_file.write(result)

def main(large_file_path, output_path, max_processes):
    #do something ...
    with open(large_file_path, 'r') as large_file, open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
        def arg_generator(large_file, output_file):
            parm1, parm2, parm3 = False, 0, []
            for line in large_file:
                if line.startswith('#'):
                    continue
                else:
                    # do something to update parm1, parm2, parm3...
                    data = line.strip().split('\t')
                    parm1 = data[0] > 0
                    parm2 = data[1]
                    parm3 = data[2:]
                    # yield
                    yield (parm1, parm2, parm3, output_file)
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_processes) as executor:
            executor.map(process, arg_generator(large_file, output_file), chunksize=int(max_processes/2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    large_path = "/path/to/large_file"
    output_path = f"para_scores.txt"
    max_processes = int(os.cpu_count()/2)# Set the maximum number of processes

    main(large_path, output_path, max_processes)
```

I ran the code on a ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS server, python 3.9.18.

So can `ProcessPoolExecutor` work with `yield` generator in Python? Or the use of `executor.map` is problemmatic? What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Please try to show valid code that represents your [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) There are too many syntax errors in the code to be certain what you're trying to achieve. Having said that, it looks like you want multiple processes writing to the same file concurrently. That's not a great idea

Comment: From the docs for [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map), _the iterables are collected immediately rather than lazily;_. That's a fancy way of saying that `map` converts your generator to a list of its yielded values. It should operate the same way as your original example.

Comment: I have edited the code. Do you mean that I should write result into a new file everytime `process` is called, then combine those files together? But `process` only generate one line everytime being called. @CtrlZ

Comment: @tdelaney That is what I expected. But things happen just like Alex Hall's answer presented below. The file handler respond nothing. Maybe it is taking too much time converting yielded values to a list so that it looks like get stuck? Or is there any python machanisms that limit the use of multiprocess?

Comment: perhaps the simplest method is to create the pool first. Then, have your for loop do executor.map whenever your list reaches some size such as 100. That keeps the list from getting large. This works well if worker execution times are relatively constant, but can cause delays if one "tall pole" calculation delays execution of the map.

Comment: I don't think either example will work because you pass a file object (well, io.TextWrapper) as a worker parameter. An exception should be raised, but you don't see it because you don't consume the result of the map operation. If you did `for _ in executor.map(process, arg_list, chunksize=int(max_processes/2)): pass`, exceptions from the pool would be seen by the parent process.

Comment: And writing a single file from multiple processes is problematic too. The processes would write blocks of the file when they reach some clib defined flush size, and multiple processes would do it simultaneously, jumbling up the file.

Comment: @tdelaney I have tried creating the pool first then do `executor.map` whenever the list reaches some size. Save the result of `process` in a list and write to the file after one batch. It seems to be working.

Comment: In the cases that the file is super large. I also believe it would be better to split the file into reasonable number of parts first by other tools (e.g. shell command). Then distributing them to multi-processes is easier. Otherwise I should wait python code to generate the list before processing, which is slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can. Here's an example:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def process(x):
    print(x * 2)


def gen():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i


def main():
    print('starting')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process, gen())
    print('done')


main()
```

Output:

```py
starting
0
2
4
done
```

The processes don't know where their arguments came from, they recieve individual items, not the entire generator. Using a generator makes no difference.

However, trying to pass an open file handle does seem to weirdly break things:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def process(f):
    print('processing', f)


def main():
    print('starting')
    with open('path_to_file.txt') as f:
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(process, [f])
    print('done')


main()
```

The output is missing the 'processing':

```
starting
done
```

Rather pass the filename as a string to each process. Use a different filename for each process so that they don't overwrite each other.

Comment: This is exactly the case I've run into. The `process` function should be called multiple times for the whole large file and the output is written into one txt file. If passing the filename, should it be `open(out_path, "a")`? Have you tried this?

Comment: Pass the filename to the process, then call `open` inside the process. If you must write to a single file, then opening in `"a"` mode is your best bet, but it'll only work if you're writing in some simple line-based format where lines from different processes can interleave.

Comment: I have edited the code. `process` only generate one line everytime being called. So lines from different processes can interleave. The only question: is it problemmatic for multiple processes writing to the same file concurrently.

Comment: @YihangZhu Yes it is potentially problematic due to possible interleaving as well as possible ordering issues

Comment: @CtrlZ I have made the code save the result in a list and write to the output file whenever the list reaches a reasonable number. Writing to file from different processes is unpredictable indeed.